# When importing a class with a companion object, what is actually imported?

Tags: scala

Let me explain that a bit further:

In one file I have the following code:

```
package test

trait MyTrait {}

class MyClass() extends MyTrait
object MyClass
```

In the other file, I have

```
import test._

val myValue : MyTrait = MyClass
```

My intention in doing so is using the `MyClass` object in this context, but still allow other people to extend the class and override the default functionality. When compiling in SBT, what I'm getting is `type mismatch; found test.MyClass.type; required test.MyTrait`. I understand that this is due the fact that I'm passing the class `MyClass`, and not an instance of it to `myValue`.

When, though, I replace, in the first file,  `object MyClass` for `object MyClass extends MyClass`, I don't get this error anymore.

My main question here is: what is actually being imported in the second file? The Class, the object, or maybe one, maybe another? What am I missing here?
Same happens if I explicitly import `MyClass` and `MyTrait` in the second file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that what is imported is all the top-level symbols in the package. So in this case that means `MyTrait`, the `MyClass` class, and the `MyClass` object.

The fact that the `MyClass` object is a companion object isn't relevant here, it could just as well be `object YourClass` and it would behave the same. The type of the companion object is not related to the type of the class.

Comment: That being, why does it work when I force the object to inherit from the class?

I mean, in the second file, when I mention `MyClass`, is it the object or the Class itself that is being referenced to?

Comment: That is just simple inheritance because the `MyClass` object now inherits from `MyClass` which inherits from `MyTrait`.

Comment: I understand, and that is the intended consequence, but, previously, it was not the object that was being passed on - rather, the class was being passed on. Why was the class being passed on, and now the object is?

Just to clarify, if I change the name of the object for, say, MyObj, without the heritance, the error becomes `type mismatch; found test.MyClass.type; required test.MyTrait`. So, in this case, it is clearly passing the object - before, though, it was passing the class, I suppose. I don't get why is the object passed on when I add inheritance.

Comment: It will become clearer if you think about types rather than objects. When you assign a value to a variable the type of the value must be compatible with the type of the variable. The type of an instance of `class MyClass` is not related to the type of `object MyClass`, so they are not compatible. But `MyClass` inherits from `MyTrait` so an instance of `MyClass` is compatible with a variable of type `MyTrait`.

Comment: I understood that. Let me rephrase my doubt:
What does `found test.MyClass.type` mean in `type mismatch; found test.MyClass.type; required test.MyTrait`?

Comment: Also, given you have already objectively answered the proposed question, I'm already accepting your answer.

Comment: Taking this backwards, the required type is `test.MyTrait` because you have declared the variable `val myValue: MyTrait` and `MyTrait` is in the `test` package. The found type is `test.MyClass.type` because the type of an `object A` is `A.type` so the type of `object MyClass` is `MyClass.type`. That fact that `test` contains `MyClass` which contains `type` does not mean that this is a type hierarchy, which is what would be needed for your code to work. It is just a namespace hierarchy.

Comment: `The type of an object A is A.type`
That is the killer sentence for me. Now I got it - thank you for your patience!